# How will Code Access Security work under .NET Framework 4?

Tags: security, .net-4.0, code-access-security

I've heard that Code Access Security is changing completely under .NET Framework 4. Can anyone confirm how this will now work, and what the implications will be for legacy applications?

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on a .NET forum or mailing list?

Comment: You don't think CAS is programming related?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's being deprecated so it really isn't being "changed" per se:
http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/11/CAS-Replaced

Comment: It's not being deprecated.  There's a whole new model which is different and in many ways better.  Definitely not deprecated though.